# ajax POST Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, jquery, post

According to this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/tX4Ls5rGEZc/BYSelqgHsCwJ android 2.3.6 has a bug with ajax POST requests.

Now I have been trying to do the proposed workaround with Content-Length:0

```
$.ajax({

surpressErrors: false,
type: "POST",
headers: {'X-HTTP-Method-Override': type, 'Content-Length':0},
url: this.serverName + request,           
async: false,             
dataType: 'json',
data: envelope,
cache: false,
success: function(data)
          {
              console.log("RESULT " + JSON.stringify(data));
              callback(data);
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              var errorMessage = error(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
              console.log('error REST post message: ' + errorMessage);
              console.log('error xhr.status message: ' + xhr.status);
              return errorMessage;
          }    
        });
```

This is not accepted by the browser however : "refused to set unsafe header"
Does anybody have a suggestion for a proper workaround ?